# Компилятор ругается на использование в константном методе не константного map

Tags: c++, const

Можно использовать map без удаления const?

```
template <typename T>
class CTest {
public:

    size_t Get(T str) const{ //Тут ругается
        return A[str];
    }

// другие методы убрал для большей понятности

private:
    map< T, size_t> A;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `[]` является *модифицирующим* методом `std::map`, по каковой причине применить его к константному `std::map` не получится.

Немодифицирующий метод называется `at`

```
return A.at(str);
```

Имейте только в виду, что он бросает исключение `std::out_of_range` в случае ненайденного ключа.

Answer (score 3):

Можно, достаточно убрать вызов оператора `[]` (который может модифицировать мапу, вставляя в нее элемент с требуемым индексом):

```
size_t Get(T const & str) const
{
    auto const p_entry{A.find(str)};
    if(A.end() == p_entry)
    {
         throw ::std::out_of_range{"not found"};
    }
    return p_entry->second;
}
```